# Are there any types of calender date picker in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hello everyone and thank you for your time.

I am trying to create a calendar view that the user may point to and click the date to auto fill the date field in my html.

If you go to Hawaiian Airlines website and click on Departing Date or Returning Date you can see an example of what I am looking for.  Here is the link.

http://www.hawaiianairlines.com/

I did research and found a very useful calender_date_select that mimics it.

http://www.rubyinside.com/calendar-date-select-a-lightweight-prototype-based-datetime-picker-for-rails-developers-573.html

If you could tell me where I could find other other sites that explain or install these kinds of calendar date pickers that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ is a commonly used datepicker

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you. Checked it out and it is exactly what I'm looking for.